# How can I format this, so I don't get an error? math.cos() error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to solve this exact equation with python, but can't seem to figure out how

```
import sympy
import scipy
import numpy


x = sympy.symbols("x")
y = sympy.symbols("y")
M= (1/x + 2*(y**2)*x)
N= (2*y*(x**2) - numpy.cos(y))
My = scipy.diff(M,y)
Nx = scipy.diff(N,x)
print('My=',My,'and Nx=',Nx,'so the equation is NOT an exact equation.')
# NOTE that M is simpler than N, so we use mu(y) for our integrating factor
Q=(Nx-My)/M
print('Q=',Q,'which is only a function of y')
# Using dsolve to find mu
mu=scipy.Function('mu')
IntFact=scipy.dsolve(scipy.diff(mu(y),y)-Q*mu(y),mu(y))
print(IntFact) # Any C will do (except 0 of course), so let C1 = 1
IntFact=scipy.exp(2*y)/y
newM=M*IntFact
newN=N*IntFact
My=scipy.diff(newM,y)
Nx=scipy.diff(newN,x)
print("New ODE is",newM,"+ (",newN.simplify(),")y' = 0")
print('My=',My,'and Nx=',Nx,'so the equation is now an exact equation.')
# Find F(x,y)
intMx=scipy.integrate(newM,x)
intNy=scipy.integrate(newN,y)
print('The integral of M dx is',intMx)
print('The integral of N dy is',intNy)
print('So F(x,y)=',intNy,'and the solution is',intNy,'= C')
```

The main error lies with this line

```
N= (2*y*(x**2) - numpy.cos(y))
```

I can't figure out how to format it so i don't get this error

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable cos method
```

I have tried formatting cos(y) as a symbol using

```
cos = sympy.symbols("cos")
```

but I am getting an error like:

```
TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not callable
```

specifically because of this line

```
  N= (2*y*(x**2) - cos(y))
```

Comment: It looks you are using `scipy` in places where you mean to use `sympy`, such as `scipy.diff`, `scipy.Function`, `scipy.dsolve`, and `scipy.integrate. NumPy and SciPy are primarily tools for *numerical* calculations, not symbolic ones.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong implementation of the `cos` function.

NumPy's `cos` function basically takes a number or an array of numbers as an argument (or something that can be treated as an array of numbers). This version of the `cos` function does not take *symbols* as input.

Now SymPy has its own trigonometric functions that *do* take symbols. Here's the page for SymPy's `cos` function: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#cos